# How to get Javascript's fs.writeFileSync to substitute in variable name as printed file name

Tags: javascript, file, fs

I want to get Javascript to write a txt file using fs.writeFileSync.  It does print when I manually write in the desired txt file name, but I want it to automatically adjust the output txt file name based on another variable which is a string.

I've tried to write it like below, but if I break it up it doesn't print anything

Working method:

```
fs.writeFileSync('Helloworld.txt', util.inspect(x, { maxArrayLength: null }))
```

---

My non-working attempt to automate the filename:

```
var name = "Helloworld"
var writer = name + ".txt , util.inspect(x, { maxArrayLength: null })"
```

And then I want to run it with:

```
fs.writeFileSync(writer)
```

My revised version doesn't give any error code.  It just doesn't print anything.  I hope someone can tell me why.  Thanks so much.

Comment: var name = "Helloworld"; fs.writeFileSync(name + '.txt', util.inspect(x, { maxArrayLength: null }))

Answer (score 1):

Then don't pass both parameters as one string argument, pass only the first one as a string argument:

```
var name = "Helloworld";
// then do
fs.writeFileSync(name + ".txt", util.inspect(x, { maxArrayLength: null }))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var writer = name + ".txt , util.inspect(x, { maxArrayLength: null })"
```

is in fact just a variable.

As per definition [fs.writeFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options)

> fs.writeFileSync(file, data[, options])

takes the first argument as the filename.

When you pass `writer` to the method it handles the string `"Helloworld.txt , util.inspect(x, { maxArrayLength: null })"` as a filename.

You can't pass both arguments with one variable.